# Jquery AJAX Response JSON Parsing

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a simple AJAX call being made which sends JSON to my server and gets a JSON response.

I have found various posts here which look like the same issue, but I can't get the final piece to work.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: 'application/json',
  cache: false,
  url: 'https://someURL.com',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    "brand": jQuery("#input_1_1_1").val(), 
    "model": jQuery("#input_1_1_2").val(), 
    "colour": jQuery("#input_1_1_3").val(), 
    "size": jQuery("#input_1_1_4").val() 
  }),
  success: function(data) {
    var result = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(result);
    console.log(result.Table1.Price);
  }
});
```

`console.log(result);` returns:

```js
{
  "Table1": [{
    "Id": 213,
    "Brand_Name": "Ray-Ban",
    "Model_Code": "0RB2219",
    "Color_Code": "1289AF",
    "Lens_Width": "59",
    "Bridge_Size": "13",
    "Temple_Length": "140",
    "Suggested_Retail_Price": 181,
    "Price": 104.54,
    "Image": "https://my.luxottica.com/myLuxotticaImages/RB/0RB2219__1289AF_890x445.jpg",
    "Prescription_Lenses": 1,
    "Varifocal": 1,
    "ClearStd": 1,
    "SunglassesStd": 1,
    "Light_Sensitive": 1,
    "ClearRB": 1,
    "SunglassesRB": 1,
    "Varilux": 1,
    "BlueLight": 1
  }]
}
```

`console.log(result.Table1.Price);` returns:

> Unable to get property 'Price' of undefined or null reference

I have tried various variations, but all seem to return undefined.

Comment: Table1 is Array

Comment: Try using result.Table1[0].Price

Comment: `data.Table1` is an array so you need to access it by index: `data.Table1[0].Price`

Comment: result is string here, you have stringified the response and assigned it to result, so you cant access properties from it like an object. You will get what you wanted from  `data.Table1[0].Price`